# How to infer individual with more than 2 properties in OWL / GraphDB?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, graphdb

I got advice from [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52190422/) and modified the source. However, the source still does not work properly.

I am using GraphDB(RuleSet: OWL2-RL) and SPARQL.

I have an ontology with Person and Animal_Lover classes. People are Animal_Lover if they have more than 2 pet.

How can I do this in my ontology?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.example.com/test"
       xmlns:test="http://www.example.com/test#"
       xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
       xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
       xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
       xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.example.com/test"/>

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.com/test#hasOwner">
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#hasPet"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.com/test#hasPet">
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#hasOwner"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.com/test#Animal_Lover">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#hasPet"/>
            <owl:minQualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">2</owl:minQualifiedCardinality>
            <owl:onClass rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#Mammal"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#Person"/>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.com/test#Mammal"/>

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.com/test#Dog">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#Mammal"/>
    <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#Person"/>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.com/test#Person">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#Mammal"/>
    <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#Dog"/>
</owl:Class>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.example.com/test#Lulu">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#Dog"/>
    <test:hasOwner rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#Smith"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.example.com/test#Tank">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#Dog"/>
    <test:hasOwner rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#Smith"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.example.com/test#Nala">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#Dog"/>
    <test:hasOwner rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#Smith"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.example.com/test#Smith">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#Person"/>
    <test:hasPet rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#Lulu"/>
    <test:hasPet rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#Nala"/>
    <test:hasPet rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/test#Tank"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

    <rdf:Description>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#AllDifferent"/>
        <owl:distinctMembers rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/test#Lulu"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/test#Nala"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/test#Smith"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/test#Tank"/>
        </owl:distinctMembers>
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I want Smith to be inferred and become Animal_Lover. But this code does not work in OWL (or GraphDB). What is the problem?

Comment: You already got an answer yesterday. and you accepted the answer. So why? Did you try to do what was suggested in the answer?

Comment: @AKSW, I confirm: it works in Protege, but it doesn't work in GraphDB. Perhaps the OP should check https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/.

Comment: @StanislavKralin that is correct. min cardinality isn't supported in equivalent class axioms, defined by `equivClassExpression :=
    Class other than owl:Thing |
    equivObjectIntersectionOf |
    ObjectHasValue |
    DataHasValue` - and to keep to short, min cardinality isn't supported at all in OWL RL profile (modulo `min 1` which indeed covered by the existential restriction implicitly).

Comment: there is another GraphDB profile called `owl-max` which claims also to cover min cardinilaty - maybe it's worth to check it out.

Comment: @AKSW Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, it does not work with `owl-max` ...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you ask for falls in OWL DL, which is not supported by GraphDB.